# How to get only place name,place id,latitude and longitude from google API?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, google-maps-api-3

I only want to fetch place name, place id, latitude, and longitude from google API. I used following APIs:

response =HTTParty.get("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location="+params[:place][:latitude]+","+params[:place[:longitude]+"&rankby=distance&types=food&key=AIzaSyAD6Vgkz7vo-nZLZp-xeNoPchOr7RepWEU&fields=results")

and
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/radarsearch/json?location=18.488091,73.813820&radius=500&types=bar|night_club&key=AIzaSyAD6Vgkz7vo-nZLZp-xeNoPchOr7RepWEU

But both are giving a lot of information to me. Is there any other api which gives me the fields mentioned above?

Answer (score 0):

well i suggest you to use geocoder and reverse geocoder instead of API.